# Any way to run multiple fullscreen EGL applications?

Tags: opengl, kms, drm

This came up while trying to launch Retroarch from Kodi on a Raspbian without X, both applications built to run on top of KMS/DRM with OpenGL ES2/EGL as the backend.

While the first application (Kodi) is running, I can launch the other one (Retroarch) and I can hear the audio from the latter in the background, but the display and input are being held by Kodi.

I was looking for some way to have basic task switching in this mode, i.e. make Kodi yield the display and input while Retroarch is running and then obtain it back.

1. Is there perhaps some tool to launch DRM applications allowing them to grab the display and input?
2. Maybe I could launch the applications in separate VTs?
3. Something else?

**Edit**: Today I obtained a result where the two applications were visible on top of each other, no idea what made it possible. Anyway, it shows that it should be possible for two applications to share an EGL display simultaneously in principle.